# Ошибка при установке Flask на Debian 8

Tags: python, debian, flask

Пытаюсь запустить пример на Flask командой `pip install -r requirements.txt`

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.10.1
```

Возникает ошибка

> Cleaning up...
>   Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-mjv2up4b/Flask/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-b0i5mgt4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mjv2up4b/Flask
>   Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log

```
~$ python -V
Python 3.4.2

~$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: `Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log` - это не помогло?

Comment: Логи содержат ту же инфу (по моему) http://pastebin.com/pMYjEg1u

Comment: `error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask': Permission denied`

Comment: Права? chmod -R 777 . или как?

Comment: лучше все-таки настроить свое окружение - VirtualEnv

Comment: А можно подробнее, ссылочку на статью какую нибудь?

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48066/discussion-between--and-maxu).

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь установить Flask в основной системе, запускать pip нужно от рута. Использование virtualenv позволяет делать то же самое, но от обычного пользователя.